# Shapeless: Generic.Aux

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless

I'm trying to understand how `Generic` works (and `TypeClass` too). The github wiki is very sparse on examples and documentation. Is there a canonical blog post / documentation page describing `Generic` and `TypeClass` in detail?

In concrete, what is the difference between these two methods?:

```
def find1[T](implicit gen: Generic[T]): Generic[T] = gen
def find2[T](implicit gen: Generic[T]): Generic[T] { type Repr = gen.Repr } = gen
```

given

```
object Generic {
  type Aux[T, Repr0] = Generic[T] { type Repr = Repr0 }
  def apply[T](implicit gen: Generic[T]): Aux[T, gen.Repr] = gen
  implicit def materialize[T, R]: Aux[T, R] = macro GenericMacros.materialize[T, R]
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The issues involved in how `Generic` and `TypeClass` are implemented and what they do are different enough that they probably deserve separate questions, so I'll stick to `Generic` here.

`Generic` provides a mapping from case classes (and potentially similar types) to heterogeneous lists. Any case class has a unique hlist representation, but any given hlist corresponds to a very, very large number of potential case classes. For example, if we have the following case classes:

```
case class Foo(i: Int, s: String)
case class Bar(x: Int, y: String)
```

The hlist representation provided by `Generic` for both `Foo` and `Bar` is `Int :: String :: HNil`, which is also the representation for `(Int, String)` and any other case classes we could define with these two types in this order.

(As a side note, `LabelledGeneric` allows us to distinguish between `Foo` and `Bar`, since it includes the member names in the representation as type-level strings.)

We generally want to be able to specify the case class and let Shapeless figure out the (unique) generic representation, and making `Repr` a type member (instead of a type parameter) allows us to do this pretty cleanly. If the hlist representation type were a type parameter, then your `find` methods would have to have a `Repr` type parameter as well, which means that you wouldn't be able to specify only the `T` and have the `Repr` inferred.

Making `Repr` a type member makes sense only because the `Repr` is uniquely determined by the first type parameter. Imagine a type class like `Iso[A, B]` that witnesses that `A` and `B` are isomorphic. This type class is very similar to `Generic`, but `A` doesn't uniquely dermine `B`—we can't just ask "what is *the* type that's isomorphic to `A`?"—so it wouldn't be useful to make `B` a type member (although we could if we really wanted to—`Iso[A]` just wouldn't really mean anything).

The problem with type members is that they're easy to forget, and once they're gone, they're gone forever. The fact that the return type of your `find1` isn't refined (i.e. doesn't include the type member) means that the `Generic` instance it returns is pretty much useless. For example, the static type of `res0` here might as well be `Any`:

```
scala> import shapeless._
import shapeless._

scala> def find1[T](implicit gen: Generic[T]): Generic[T] = gen
find1: [T](implicit gen: shapeless.Generic[T])shapeless.Generic[T]

scala> case class Foo(i: Int, s: String)
defined class Foo

scala> find1[Foo].to(Foo(1, "ABC"))
res0: shapeless.Generic[Foo]#Repr = 1 :: ABC :: HNil

scala> res0.head
<console>:15: error: value head is not a member of shapeless.Generic[Foo]#Repr
              res0.head
                   ^
```

When Shapeless's `Generic.materialize` macro creates the `Generic[Foo]` instance we're asking for, it's statically typed as a `Generic[Foo] { type Repr = Int :: String :: HNil }`, so the `gen` argument that the compiler hands to `find1` has all the static information we need. The problem is that we then explicitly up-cast that type to a plain old unrefined `Generic[Foo]`, and from that point on the compiler doesn't know what the `Repr` is for that instance.

Scala's path-dependent types give us a way not to forget the refinement *without* adding another type parameter to our method. In your `find2`, the compiler statically knows the `Repr` for the incoming `gen`, so when you say that the return type is `Generic[T] { type Repr = gen.Repr }`, it will be able to keep track of that information:

```
scala> find2[Foo].to(Foo(1, "ABC"))
res2: shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil]] = 1 :: ABC :: HNil

scala> res2.head
res3: Int = 1
```

To sum up: `Generic` has a type parameter `T` that uniquely determines its type member `Repr`, `Repr` is a type member instead of a type parameter so that we don't have to include it in all of our type signatures, and path-dependent types make this possible, allowing us to keep track of `Repr` even though it's not in our type signatures.

Comment: Why not 
```def find2[T](implicit gen: Generic[T]): Generic.Aux[T,gen.Repr] = gen``` ?

Comment: @crak You can write that as well—it's exactly equivalent to using the type refinement. I think people often get hung up on `Aux`, though, when it's really just a syntactic convenience, so I left it out of this answer.

Comment: Travis, I've just wanted to say I really appreciate reading your answers and blog posts on shapeless. Nontrivial stuff very well explained. Keep it up!

Comment: @TravisBrown Awesome and clear explanation, thanks!  

I was going to write that I still don't get why the compiler can't figure out the correct type for `Generic#Repr`, but I just realized that there is no such relationship at all in the definition of Generic:

`    trait Generic[T] extends Serializable {
      type Repr
      def to(t : T) : Repr
      def from(r : Repr) : T
    }
`
and so `Generic#Repr` it's "opaque" unless we set the type explicitly.