# Map single type HList to HList of target types

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have trait-marker

```
trait TypedTrait {
  type TYPE
}
```

and the realization

```
case class TypedString[U](value: String) extends TypedTrait {
  type TYPE = U
}
```

And I want to map `HList` of `String` into `HList` of `TypedString` in accordance with `TypedString`'s type parameters.

The simplest way is to create `convert` method (as described in [Shapeless map HList depending on target types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36515901/shapeless-map-hlist-depending-on-target-types)):

```
    val list = "Hello" :: "world" :: HNil

    val mapped: TypedString[Int] :: TypedString[Boolean] :: HNil =
           convert[TypedString[Int] :: TypedString[Boolean] :: HNil](list)
```

But I'd like to avoid redundant parameterization and use something like this:

```
    val mapped: TypedString[Int] :: TypedString[Boolean] :: HNil =
               convert[Int :: Boolean :: HNil](list)
```

Complete code example for the first solution:

```
      import shapeless._

      trait TypedTrait {
        type TYPE
      }

      case class TypedString[U](value: String) extends TypedTrait {
        type TYPE = U
      }

      trait Convert[I <: HList, O <: HList] { def apply(i: I): O }

      object Convert extends LowPriorityConvertInstances {
        implicit val convertHNil: Convert[HNil, HNil] = new Convert[HNil, HNil] {
          def apply(i: HNil): HNil = i
        }

        implicit def convertHConsTS[TS, T <: HList, TO <: HList](implicit
                                                                  c: Convert[T, TO]
                                                                 ): Convert[String :: T, TypedString[TS] :: TO] =
          new Convert[String :: T, TypedString[TS] :: TO] {
            def apply(i: String :: T): TypedString[TS] :: TO = TypedString[TS](i.head) :: c(i.tail)
          }
      }

      sealed class LowPriorityConvertInstances {
        implicit def convertHCons[H, T <: HList, TO <: HList](implicit
                                                              c: Convert[T, TO]
                                                             ): Convert[H :: T, H :: TO] = new Convert[H :: T, H :: TO] {
          def apply(i: H :: T): H :: TO = i.head :: c(i.tail)
        }
      }


      class PartiallyAppliedConvert[O <: HList] {
        def apply[I <: HList](i: I)(implicit c: Convert[I, O]): O = c(i)
      }

      def convert[O <: HList]: PartiallyAppliedConvert[O] =
        new PartiallyAppliedConvert[O]

      val list = "Hello" :: "world" :: HNil

      val mapped: TypedString[Int] :: TypedString[String] :: HNil =
         convert[TypedString[Int] :: TypedString[String] :: HNil](list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this by having three `HList` type arguments in `Convert`:

- the type of the actual `HList` passed to `convert` (e.g., `String :: String :: HNil`)
- the type parameter prescribed by the user (e.g., `Int :: Boolean :: HNil`)
- the output type – basically the prescribed `HList` wrapped in `TypedString`: e.g., `TypedString[Int] :: TypedString[Boolean] :: HNil`.

The output type can be completely calculated from the prescribed `HList`, so I'd use the [`Aux` pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725935/shapeless-generic-aux) commonly employed with `shapeless` code:

```
trait Convert[In <: HList, Prescribed <: HList] {
  type Out <: HList
  def apply(i: In): Out
}

object Convert {
  type Aux[I <: HList, P <: HList, O <: HList] = Convert[I, P] { type Out = O }

  // Adapt the implicits accordingly. 
  // The low priority one is left as an exercise to the reader.

  implicit val convertHNil: Convert.Aux[HNil, HNil, HNil] = 
    new Convert[HNil, HNil] {
      type Out = HNil
      def apply(i: HNil): HNil = i
    }

  implicit def convertHConsTS[TS, TI <: HList, TP <: HList, TO <: HList](implicit
    c: Convert.Aux[TI, TP, TO]
  ): Convert.Aux[String :: TI, TS :: TP, TypedString[TS] :: TO] =
    new Convert[String :: TI, TS :: TP] {
      type Out = TypedString[TS] :: TO
      def apply(i: String :: TI): TypedString[TS] :: TO = 
        TypedString[TS](i.head) :: c(i.tail)
    }
}  

class PartiallyAppliedConvert[P <: HList] {
  def apply[I <: HList](i: I)(implicit c: Convert[I, P]): c.Out = c(i)
}

def convert[O <: HList]: PartiallyAppliedConvert[O] =
  new PartiallyAppliedConvert[O]

val list = "Hello" :: "world" :: HNil

val mapped = convert[Int :: String :: HNil](list)
```

Result:

```
scala> mapped
res3: shapeless.::[com.Main.TypedString[Int],shapeless.::[com.Main.TypedString[String],shapeless.HNil]] = TypedString(Hello) :: TypedString(world) :: HNil
```

---

I believe it may be possible to achieve this using some operations provided with `shapeless` (`shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapped`, `shapeless.ops.hlist.HKernel`, or [`shapeless.ops.hlist.RightFolder`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288806/dynamically-parametrize-poly1-function-in-shapeless/25316124) look appropriate), but I don't know how to write a `Poly` function, that takes a type argument and a normal argument. Any tips would be welcome.